# Simple UITableView DrillDown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have created a simple UITableView drill down were the user can click through a UITableView and then get to another view and back again. I did this by following [this tutorial](http://iphoneproghelp.blogspot.com/2008/12/uitableview-part-iii.html)

However, I don't want the first screen that the user sees to be a table view, but i am unsure how to make it so that the TableView will be deeper inside the program, and the only tutorials I find show how to make it the first screen you come to. Could someone just write out a couple of quick steps, nothing fancy, to tell me how to do this? Or point me to a tutorial that might be of some help. Thanks!

Comment: @Disco S2's answer is the best way to do it.. I had done it the exact same way when I was first learning how to bring in subviews and stuff..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this many ways but the way I would do it (may not be right) is like so.

You have a view controller, and this view controller loads with a view. On this view have a button. Only once this button is pressed do you slide the table view ontop.
So instead of having a designated UITableViewController you make a normal UIViewController a TableViewControllerDelegate and a TableViewDataSource. This way you can still organise your views whilst populating and controlling your table view all within the same view controller.

Comment: If i post my code do you think you could take a look? I really have no idea why this is so confusing.

Comment: or point me to a tutorial that has the drill down located somewhere inside the program, not right on the top?